# How to list hierarchy/tree structure of shell scipt?

Tags: linux, shell

Assume we have three shell scripts which are called A1, A2 and A3.
A1 will call A2 and A2 will call A3.

Is there any command that can list the tree structure of them? Say `shelltree`

```
shelltree A1
```

Results would like:

```
A1
 |---A2
        |---A3
```

Comment: Having run this script, the commands called would be visible as a process tree (assuming they're called via normal fork+exec and not `source` or `exec` with no fork.)

Comment: `strace -f -e trace=execve bash A1` might be a starting point - you'd have to postprocess the output to get what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pstree`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pstree) which shows running processes as a tree.

For example:

```
$ bash -c '(bash -c "sleep 20"); sleep 20' &
[1] 23863
$ pstree $(pgrep -fn bash)
-+= 23863 user bash -c (bash -c "sleep 20"); sleep 20
 \--- 23864 user sleep 20
```

Usage:

```
pstree -p [pid ...]
```

---

Or more sophisticated example (based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225800/21471)):

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$1
f(){ let d--; if [ $d -gt 0 ]; then bash -x $0 $d $$; else [ $d -eq 0 ]  && pstree -p $$; fi }; f
```

Output:

```
$ bash foo.sh 5
+ pstree -p 76216
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 00231 kenorb /sbin/launchd
   \-+= 00246 kenorb /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn_0_49164
     \-+= 70321 root login -pfl kenorb /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /usr/local/bin/bash
       \-+= 70322 kenorb -bash
         \-+= 76212 kenorb bash foo.sh 5
           \-+- 76213 kenorb bash -x foo.sh 4 76212
             \-+- 76214 kenorb bash -x foo.sh 3 76213
               \-+- 76215 kenorb bash -x foo.sh 2 76214
                 \-+- 76216 kenorb bash -x foo.sh 1 76215
                   \-+- 76217 kenorb pstree -p 76216
                     \--- 76218 root ps -axwwo user,pid,ppid,pgid,command
```

Comment: What if the program has to run a long period or doesn't finish properly, can I sill list the complete tree?

Comment: @KenT As long as there is a process running, you get the tree. If you want to keep the tree for the previously running processes, you need to store it somewhere (like into the variable), before the program exits.

Comment: It seems that if A spawns B, C and D sequentially. pstree can only list the tree of A-B, A-C or A-D. How can I list them all?

Comment: @KenT Try adding `-p` to `pstree`, I've updated with the new example.